# Set of all rational numbers less than given computable real number is decidable

Tags: computability, mathematical-analysis

> Prove that set of rational numbers less than given computable real
>   number is decidable

This problem was in my exam yesterday, but I was not able to solve it. However I still want to give it another try.

Same problem can be stated in this way: 
Construct an algorithm, which answers the question: Is our given rational number less or greater than their(fixed) computable number?

Here's my poor try so far.

Since it's analysis related problem, I used the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of computable number, which is: 
$\exists f$ computable function, such that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}, f$ gives us $\delta > 0, \delta \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that$|a - \delta| \leq \epsilon$ holds for given computable number $a$

Let $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ be our input, and let $f$ compute for us 2 rationals $q_1$ and $q_2$. It is well known that $|q_1 - q_2| < 2\epsilon$

Now let's choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2^{i}}, i = 0,1,2,...$
For each $i$-th step I compute $f$ twice and get $q_{i_{1}},q_{i_{2}}$. I think that our given rational $p$ should hold some condition with both $q_{i_1},q_{i_2}$ which will help me to finish the algorithm, but I couldn't figure this out. I believe there are finitely many checks for each step which will let me know that for example $p < a$ just like in picture below.

[image]

What do you think about this problem? Maybe there's more straightforward way to prove this. Thank you.

Comment: It isn't decidable whether a given computable number is non-negative or not (even Wikipedia knows that!), so I don't think that what the question is asking is actually possible.

Comment: hmm.. similar problem comes from my textbook, but uses number $e$ instead of arbitrary computable number, is it change something?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus But here the computable real number is fixed, and we are given a rational number to check. We don't need a uniform solution on the real. We only need to prove that for any comp. real we have an algorithm working on rationals.

Comment: You can solve it for $e$ since it's given as the limit of a rational series with vanishing bounds on the tail, but you can't solve it in general.

Comment: can't we construct a Cauchy sequence for it just by using the above definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this problem as follows. Let $a$ be the computable real, and $A = \{x\in\mathbb{Q}\ |\ x<a\}$.

If $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $A$ is decidable since $x<a$ is a comparison between rationals, which is decidable.

Otherwise, we can assume $a$ is irrational. Our algorithm performs the following.
First, we take the candidate $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ as input.
We then query $f$ (the function which approximates $a$ as requested) repeatedly with $q=2^{-n}$ for every $n>0$.
Eventually, for some $n$ we will obtain one of

$$
f(2^{-n}) + 2^{-n} < x
\qquad \lor\qquad
x < f(2^{-n}) - 2^{-n}
$$
Indeed, this will happen as soon as $2^{-n} < |x-a| / 2$, which is a possibility because we know $x \neq a$.

In the first case, we return $x > a$ ($x \notin A$), in the second we return $x<a$ ($x \in A$).

The correctness comes from
$$
a \leq f(2^{-n}) + 2^{-n}
\qquad \land\qquad
f(2^{-n}) - 2^{-n} \leq a
$$
being true for all $n$.

---

Note that this solution is not uniform in $a$. That is, we only prove that there is an algorithm for any computable $a$, taking a candidate rational $x$ as input. We do *not* show that there is a single algorithm that, given both $a$ and $x$ as input is able to decide $<$ (indeed, that would be undecidable).

Comment: How does the algorithm check that $a \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @CraigGidney It does not (and can not). This is covered by the very last comment on the non-uniformity of the solution. We only prove that for any $a$ there is an algorithm: for this it is enough to choose one algorithm for rational $a$, and another one for irrational $a$.